# CORS google-trends-api through Vue JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, cors, axios

I have the google-trends-api package pulled in through npm. I am running laravel with VueJS. I try to make a request using Vue but I get the following error -  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydevserver.test' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
I have tried adding the headers Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to my virtual host block on apache on my mac however I still get the error.

Here are the request headers -

```
:authority: trends.google.com
:method: GET
:path: /trends/api/explore?hl=en-US&req=%7B%22comparisonItem%22%3A%5B%7B%22keyword%22%3A%22poly%20mailers%22%2C%22hl%22%3A%22en-US%22%2C%22category%22%3A0%2C%22timezone%22%3A240%2C%22property%22%3A%22%22%2C%22endTime%22%3A%222018-04-08T04%3A54%3A49.617Z%22%2C%22startTime%22%3A%222004-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%2C%22time%22%3A%222004-01-1%202018-04-8%22%7D%5D%2C%22category%22%3A0%2C%22property%22%3A%22%22%7D&tz=240
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
dnt: 1
origin: http://mydevserver.test
save-data: on
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
x-client-data: CIa2yQEIo7bJAQjBtskBCKmdygEIqKPKARiSo8oB
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: I tried this package and it didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: check the *browser* **developer** tools console/network tab, specifically checking the request to whatever the "cross origin" server is - if CORS headers are not present in the response from the server, then the server isn't sending them, and the code you posted in the question is irrelevant

Comment: solution that i not recommend http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: `"I have tried adding the headers Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to my virtual host block on apache on my mac"` - is that the "cross origin" server? or is that the server serving your page?

Comment: server serving my page...i added the request info and the headers are not being sent depsite it in my apache and in the barryvdh/laravel-cors package. I think it is in the npm package somewhere.